# What is the difference between numpy.sqrt(x**2+y**2) and for loop

Tags: python, computer-vision, canny-operator

I'm practicing the Canny Edge Detector algorithm, when I calculated the [edge strength](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPSpI.png) I used two different formulas:

```py
    es1 = np.ones((jx.shape[0],jx.shape[1]))
    es1 = np.sqrt(jx**2+jy**2)
    es1 = (es1/es1.max())*255
```

and

```py
    es = np.ones((jx.shape[0],jx.shape[1]))
    for i in range(jx.shape[0]):
        for j in range(jx.shape[1]):
            es[i,j] = np.sqrt((jx[i,j])**2+(jy[i,j])**2)
    es = (es/es.max())*255
```

The `jx` and `jy` means the result of vertical edge detection and horizontal edge detection, I got two very different results, and I want to know why does the difference occurs, is it because of a mathematical mistake?

[es](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpt9v.png) and [es1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EA5cS.png) resault.

Comment: The difference is the type of the values used in the computations (float vs (I presume) 8-bit ints).

Comment: Yes! That is where the shoe pinches. I found that the type of es1 is np.float64 and es is np.float16!